# Ubuntu 18 - Stuck at grub rescue

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

**Stuck at rescue mode**

```
grub rescue> set                                                                
cmdpath=(hd0)                                                                   
prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub                                                   
root=hd0,msdos1
                                                             
grub rescue> ls                                                                 
(hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1)    
                                   
grub rescue> ls /                                                               
./ ../ lost+found/ etc/ media/ bin/ boot/ dev/ home/ lib/ lib64/ mnt/ opt/ proc/
root/ run/ sbin/ srv/ sys/ tmp/ usr/ var/ initrd.img vmlinuz initrd.img.old vml
inuz.old org/ .rnd           
                                               
grub rescue> insmod normal                                                      
error: relocation 0x0 is not implemented yet.                                   
grub rescue>    

grub rescue> insmod linux                                                       
error: relocation 0x0 is not implemented yet.

grub rescue> insmod (hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/i386-pc/linux.mod                    
error: relocation 0x0 is not implemented yet.                                   
grub rescue>
```

I tried several commands with no luck, any ideas what might be happening?

Thanks!

Comment: Im connected to the equipment via a console cable, so Im not able to connect it to other equipment.

Comment: Its not a valid command:

grub rescue> grub-install --target=x86_64-efi /dev/sda
Unknown command `grub-install'.
grub rescue>

Comment: Ubuntu 18?  So this is a Ubuntu Core 18 server?   (the Ubuntu products using the *year* format (18) are different to the far more common *year.month* format (18.04))

Answer (score 0):

Found the error, the mods were in /usr/lib/grub so the prefix is:

```
set prefix=/usr/lib/grub
```